# ASP.NET MVC : RenderAction for action writing image throws exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an action returning an image:

```
    public void SensorData(int id, int width = 300, int height = 100)
    {
        using (var repo = new DataRepository())
        {
            var sensor = repo.GetSensor(id);
            if (sensor == null) return;

            var chart = new Chart(width, height);
            chart.AddSeries(name: "Values", 
                            chartType: "line", 
                            xValue: sensor.DataValues.Select(s => s.Date).ToList(),
                            yValues: sensor.DataValues.Select(s => s.Value).ToList());

            chart.Write();
        }
    }
```

This action renders fine when i call it from the browser (ex. controller_name/SensorData/6). The problem is that when i try to view it using Html.RenderAction i get the following compilation exception on my view:

**The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments.**

This is the code generating the exception:

```
@Html.RenderAction("SensorTypes", new { id = 6});
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Won't this write out image data into a webpage, which is presumably not what you want?

Comment: This is the way in which most samples on Charts inside MVC that i found were written

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't embed the image data directly in the HTML.
Try using an image tag and pointing to the action instead.

```
<img src='@Url.Action("SensorTypes", new { id = 6})'  />
```

Answer (score 5):

You have two possibilities:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("SensorTypes", new { id = 6 });}
```

or:

```
@Html.Action("SensorTypes", new { id = 6 })
```

Contrast this with their equivalents using the WebForms view engine:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("SensorTypes", new { id = 6 }); %>
<%= Html.Action("SensorTypes", new { id = 6 }) %>
```